# Find the number of internal angles of a polygon, bigger than 180º

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon

How can I find the number of internal angles of a polygon, bigger than 180º,
having only the vertices of the polygon?

For each vertex I want always the internal angle, not the external.

Thanks from Brazil.

Comment: You can't define a polygon merely by vertices. You _have_ to specify the sides too.

Comment: I have the vertex in order, so I don't need the sides.

Comment: The vertices define to points which would be connected (the sides) in order to give the polygon.

Comment: Haha. Good one. You remind me one of those mathematics classes in campus....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine the angle of two vectors simply by taking the scalar product (dot product).  A useful property is that if the vectors are orthogonal, their scalar product is zero; if their angle is obtuse, the product is negative, otherwise positive.  So, the steps to take are:

- find the first edge from V0 to V1 (as a vector, you get this by subtracting the coordinates), then rotate it by 90 degrees to the left (this is just transforming `(x y)` to `(-y x)`)
- find the second edge from V1 to V2 (not rotated)
- take the scalar product (this is just `(x1 * x2) + (y1 * y2)`)
- if the scalar product is negative, it is a right turn, otherwise a left turn
- next edge...
- if you go through the vertices counter-clockwise, count the number of right turns, otherwise the number of left turns
- for the last vertex, you have to return to the first (i.e. use the edges Vn to V0 and V0 to V1)

*edit*: You can find whether the vertices are ordered counter-clockwise or clockwise by using the following formula to calculate the polygon's area:

```
     1  n-1
A = --- SUM( x(i)*y(i+1) - x(i+1)*y(i) )
     2  i=0
```

where `n` is the number of vertices. `x(n)` and `y(n)` are the same as `x(0)` and `y(0)` (to close the polygon).

If it is positive, then the vertices are ordered counter-clockwise, otherwise clockwise.

*edit*: When you simplify the steps of rotation and scalar product, you arrive at the formula for the two-dimensional cross product, `x1*y2 - x2*y1`. This simplifies the first steps above:

- find the first edge from V0 to V1 (as a vector, by subtracting the coordinates)
- dito for the second edge from V1 to V2
- take the cross product `((x1 * y2) - (x2  * y1))`
- if the cross product is positive, it is a left turn

Sorry for the convoluted first approach.

Comment: Could you define scalar product?

Comment: Probably the dot product. It's a lot easier to use the cross product since that is well defined assuming you know the winding.

Comment: Scalar product: x1 * x2 + y1 * y2 = scalar

Comment: Where x# and y# stand for the x- and y-displacement associated with vector #, that is, _not_ the coordinates of the endpoints.

Comment: "probably"?  There is no ambiguity here.  I didn't realize that in english, "scalar product" is the less known name, but every math site I could google up said "The dot product, also known as scalar product or inner product...".  Added hint in text.

Comment: Harleqin, how can I do the rotation?

Comment: It is just as I wrote: new_x = - old_y; new_y = old_x;

Comment: Harleqin, and if the scalar product is zero. Is it a right or a left turn?

Comment: Well, that is the case when three vertices are exactly linear.  It is up to you how you want to handle that case.  It would be strange to call the middle one a vertex of the polygon, since it is just some point on one edge, but this might happen, e.g. when the vertices are determined randomly.

Comment: Well, this solution will work only if you know beforehand where the sequence of vertices is clockwise or anti-clockwise. The question doesn't say whether we know that or not.

Comment: That is a good point.  You can determine that by calculating the polygon area.  I add the formula.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) of the vertices.
2. Identify the vertices that *do not* lie on the convex hull. These are your candidate vertices with >180 external angles.
3. For each such vertex investigate further about the angle (Can't think of any way right now but you can extend this).

Comment: For single vertices excluded from the convex hull, the interior angle is >180. For a series of vertices, recursively study the convex hull of the polygon formed by the excluded vertices and the included vertices at either end of the series.

Comment: This answer has got it backwards -- the most efficient way of finding the convex hull of a simple polygon _involves_ finding the concave inner angles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is an irregular polygon, since it would be really difficult for a regular polygon to have an internal angle greater than 180 degrees.

For each vertex, you would also need to know the two neighboring vertices.  You can then turn this into a trigonometry problem, where you find the angle from the main vertex to, say, the left vertex, and add it to the angle from the main vertex to the right vertex.

For example,

```
tan(angle_to_left) = (v.y-left.x)/(v.y-left.y)
tan(angle_to_right) = (v.y-right.x)/(v.y-right.y)
```

Then add the angles together.

Finally, for all angles that are greater than 180, increment a counter.  After going through all of the vertices, your counter will tell you how many internal angles are greater than 180.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with tangent is when x==0. If you only know the vertices of the polygon, you don't know enough unless it's a triangle since they could have any sort of connectivity.

Assuming you know the connectivity, you will then need to calculate the winding order (i.e., in what direction do the points go around the polygon?). With the winding order, you can then take the cross product of every point with its neighboring points and take the inverse sine of magnitude of that to get the angle.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the interior angle of the last two vectors (as an example), we need to implement this equation for the last two vectors of the polygon:

angleRadians = Math.acos((vx1 * vx2 + vy1 * vy2) / ( Math.sqrt( vx1*vx1 + vy1*vy1 ) * Math.sqrt( vx2*vx2 + vy2*vy2 ) ));

this is using the Dot product of the vectors. If you have questions on this, [here's a tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98C7iv8OcnI&list=FLp1JCtUAt1iLLUN6Sc74HQg&feature=mh_lolz)

But that does not take into account the 'winding direction', first you must get the cross product and, if the cross product is positive, it was a left turn, if negative--a right turn (for which we will compensate by subtracting (ext) angle from 360.

I've included my JS code here, as a gist: https://gist.github.com/3741816.

:D

Answer (score -1):

This is a question related to geometry, not exactly progamming related.

If you have the vertices, you can just find the internal angles by trigonometry, similar to how you find the angles of a triangle.

Using three adjacent vertices, imagine a triangle and them find the internal angles.

For example, look at the polygon:

[image: Polygon]

We can construct a triangle as:

[image: Construct internal triangle]